# Meteor regex find() far slower than in MongoDB console

Tags: regex, mongodb, meteor

I've been researching A LOT for past 2 weeks and can't pinpoint the exact reason of my Meteor app returning results too slow.

Currently I have only a single collection in my Mongo database with around 2,00,000 documents. And to search I am using Meteor subscriptions on the basis of a given keyword. Here is my query:

```
db.collection.find({$or:[
{title:{$regex:".*java.*", $options:"i"}}, 
{company:{$regex:".*java.*", $options:"i"}}
]})
```

When I run above query in `mongo` shell, the results are returned instantly. But when I use it in Meteor client, the results take almost 40 seconds to return from server. Here is my meteor client code:

```
Template.testing.onCreated(function () {
    var instance = this;
    // initialize the reactive variables
    instance.loaded = new ReactiveVar(0);
    instance.limit = new ReactiveVar(20);
    instance.autorun(function () {

    // get the limit
    var limit = instance.limit.get();
    var keyword = Router.current().params.query.k;
    var searchByLocation = Router.current().params.query.l;
    var startDate = Session.get("startDate");
    var endDate = Session.get("endDate");

    // subscribe to the posts publication
    var subscription = instance.subscribe('sub_testing', limit,keyword,searchByLocation,startDate,endDate);
    // if subscription is ready, set limit to newLimit
    $('#searchbutton').val('Searching');
    if (subscription.ready()) {
        $('#searchbutton').val('Search');
        instance.loaded.set(limit);
    } else {
        console.log("> Subscription is not ready yet. \n\n");
    }
});

instance.testing = function() {
    return Collection.find({}, {sort:{id:-1},limit: instance.loaded.get()});
}
```

And here is my meteor server code:

```
Meteor.publish('sub_testing', function(limit,keyword,searchByLocation,startDate,endDate) {
    Meteor._sleepForMs(200);
    var pat = ".*" + keyword + ".*";
    var pat2 = ".*" + searchByLocation + ".*";

    return Jobstesting.find({$or:[{title:{$regex: pat, $options:"i"}}, { company:{$regex:pat,$options:"i"}},{ description:{$regex:pat,$options:"i"}},{location:{$regex:pat2,$options:"i"}},{country:{$regex:pat2,$options:"i"}}],$and:[{date_posted: { $gte : endDate, $lt: startDate }},{sort:{date_posted:-1},limit: limit,skip: limit});
});
```

One point I'd also like to mention here that I use `"Load More"` pagination and by default the `limit` parameter gets 20 records. On each `"Load More"` click, I increment the `limit` parameter by 20 so on first click it is `20`, on second click `40` and so on...

Any help where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it help if you change `.*java.*` with `[^j]*(?:j(?!ava)[^j]*)*java.*`?

Comment: @stribizhev No it doesn't. The fact is `java` is a keyword I'm searching against. It can be dynamic and I don't want to deal with such complex regex you've shared and splitting up the keyword I have. All I need is to find if a keyword occurs in title or description or any other field of my interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I use it in Meteor client, the results take almost 40 seconds to return from server.

You may be misunderstanding how Meteor is accessing your data.

Queries run on the client are processed on the client.

- `Meteor.publish` - Makes data available on the server
- `Meteor.subscribe` - Downloads that data from the server to the client.
- `Collection.find` - Looks through the data on the client.

If you think the Meteor side is slow, you should time it server side (print time before/after) and file a bug.

If you're implementing a pager, you might try a meteor method instead, or 
a [pager package](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages).

Comment: Actually I have understood how meteor deals with 2 datasets - client and server. And server subscription syncs data to the client and any change done on client database is captured by meteor template which thus updates the rendered view. 
The issue is even if I am loading the very first page which has a hard-coded limit of 20 documents to be queried and send to client, it takes 40 seconds. 
Can you give me some guidance how can I find where the bottleneck is? I usually learn by example and mongo's profiling documentation is not that good IMHO @michael-cole

Comment: @khalid `console.log( (new Date()).toLocaleString() );` before/after `return Jobstesting.find()`  Either, it's running over and over, or it's indexes, or its a bug.  You'll need to save the value before returning it to see the second console.log().

Comment: I'd really recommend looking through the code of an existing pager package if you're determined to make your own.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the pager package, I'll look into some of them. Another thing I also found is that some people say Meteor is not ideal for such use case and is only good if you need a reactive application transferring small chunks of data like chat applications etc. Can you suggest me any source where I can know which node.js based stack is ideal for which use-case? As far as I have made my app, I just developed it in Meteor because Meteor is the only highly praised framework in Node.js apart from Express but with Express you have to do a lot of work yourself.

Comment: @khalid, MEAN stack (Express) and Meteor are the most common.  Part of becoming a developer is trying the different frameworks out and seeing for yourself.  There's alot of money involved, so anyone saying it's easy is selling something.  [http://todomvc.com/](http://todomvc.com/) is a site dedicated to making the same app in many different frameworks, so you can see the code.  A cynic would say they all suck in some way which is why there isn't just one :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to debug the issue which was "it's running over and over" as you had predicted :) It's working great now Yay!